# how to create a class in classic jscript?

Tags: javascript, jscript

how to create a class in classic jscript? (not jscript.net)

And, how to reference this class?.

I tried with

```
class someclass {


}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes. And you don't need them. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function

Comment: it is not javascript but jscript

Comment: JScript is Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript. JavaScript was originally developed Netscape, adapted by Microsoft as JScript. Later, JavaScript was standardized as ECMAScript. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript

Comment: Probably the following answer might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11144431/476712

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not classes as such, but here's a simple example of how to get basic object-oriented functionality. If this is all you need, great, but if you're after other features of classes, such as inheritance, someone more knowledgeable than myself will have to help.

```
function SomeClass(n) {
    this.some_property = n;
    this.some_method = function() {
        WScript.Echo(this.some_property);
    };
}

var foo = new SomeClass(3);
var bar = new SomeClass(4);
foo.some_method();
bar.some_property += 2;
bar.some_method();
```

Comment: Not really, it is clear. Though, the "alert" function does not work.

Comment: This makes me want to flag it as very low quality

Comment: @magallanes it does not work because `this` inside the function is not referring to the "class"

Comment: @Felix and others- My hope was that a bare-bones example would be sufficiently clear. At least, I personally often prefer to learn from such examples.

Comment: @magellanes: *Though, the "alert" function does not work* -> you're not running this in a browser context (e.g. wsh)?

Comment: again, it is jscript (server side). not javascript (client side) but the class definition works so it is ok for me.

Comment: @magallanes no worries. Replaced it with `WScript.Echo`. it should work now.

Answer (score 7):

There are no classes in jscript. You can make an object constructor:

```
function someclass() {
  this.answer = 42;
}
```

You use it like a class:

```
var obj = new someclass();
```

To make methods you add functions to its prototype:

```
someclass.prototype.getAnswer = function() {
  return this.answer;
}
```

Usage:

```
var ans = obj.getAnswer();
```

Answer (score 2):

Most recent:

- [JavaScript/Reference/Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

---

Answer from 2011:

You don't really have classes on Javascript, but you have something similar. [Check this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dA8Yy/)

```
var classA = function() {     // declaring a "class"
    this.something = "Text";  // a public class field
};

classA.prototype.b = " b ";   // a class field
classA.c = "c";               // a static field
classA.prototype.d = function(x) { // a public class method
};
classA.e = function(x){     // a public static method
};

var a = new classA();       // instantiate a class
```

[Read more on MDC...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: What is the difference between a "public class field", "class field", and a "static field"? same for methods? Would appreciate it if you could add examples.

Comment: @Foad my answer here is from 2011, please don't even use it in the future, instead see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Hmmm , I don't think that's applicable to JScript classic.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function with the name of the class.  Any var defined within it as `this.whatever` will act as a class member:

```
function SomeClass() {
  this.a;
  this.b;
}
```

Then add methods to the prototype:

```
SomeClass.prototype.methodA = function() {
  this.a++;
}

SomeClass.prototype.methodB = function() {
  this.b++;
}
```

I believe you can also define methods inside the constructor like this, but I've not used this syntax for a long time.

```
function SomeClass {
   this.a = 0;

   // Method definition
   this.methodA = function() {
      this.a++;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Felix Kling Already noticed my error before your comment and fixed.  Thanks.`

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me as I only faintly grasp this myself:

Javascript does not have classes. It has objects. To replicate a class, you create an object. To create "instances" of that "class", you duplicate that object. There are a few ways to do this. One is to create a function that returns an object, then call the function, like so:

```
function Car(brand, year) {
return {
brand: brand,
year: year
}
}
var modelT = Car("Ford", 1900); //or whenever the model T came out
modelT.brand == "Ford" //true
modelT.year == 1900; //true
```

Another way is to create an object that is a function and create a "new" of that object. The catch is you have to use `new`, and that's rather misleading.

```
var Car = function(make, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.year = year;
};
var x =  new Car("ford", 1990);
//same tests hold true from earlier example
```

In my opinion the best way is to use `Object.create` because it best represents what's actually happening:

```
var Car = (function() {
    var self = Object.create({}, {
        make: {
value: "Ford"
}
year: {
value: 1900
}
    });
    return self;
})();
var modelT = Object.create(Car, {
                        make: {
                            value: "Model T"
                        },
year: {
value: 1901
}
                    });
```

Unfortunately, this is extremely cumbersome.

### Edit:

This is an extremely helpful resource: [JavaScript "classes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181102/javascript-classes)

Comment: yes, but it is jscript that it is similar to javascript but (thanks Microsoft) is not javascript.  *_*

Comment: @magallanes yes, but the same principles and most of the same syntax (except `Object.create`) still apply.

Answer (score -1):

Classes in Jscript (.Net?):  http://www.functionx.com/jscript/Lesson05.htm

And Powershell supports it (as well as VisualBasic, even F#).  Now I see the question says not in .net.  But in my defense, I was googling jscript classes, and this is where I landed.

```
Add-Type @'
class FRectangle {
  var Length : double;
  var Height : double;
  function Perimeter() : double {
      return (Length + Height) * 2; }
  function Area() : double {
      return Length * Height;  } }
'@ -Language JScript


[frectangle]::new()


Length Height
------ ------
     0      0
```